# Evolution 3.18: "Mark as read" per mailbox?

Tags: email, evolution

I use Evolution at my office in which I share a couple of mailboxes with other members of my team. When I access my personal mailbox I want to have an email in my inbox marked as read as soon as I mark it in the inbox, but for the shared mailboxes I do not want this function.

So my question is: Is it possible to set different "Marked as read"-policies on different mailboxes in Evolution?